# Not sure how to start this FOL proof-- why is vE not a good move on line 4? Thx!

Tags: logic

[image: FOL proof here]

I'm stuck on line 4. Perhaps I should start with a different sub-proof?

Comment: You are thinking of "disjunctive syllogism", a similarly named rule of inference. $$\dfrac{p\vee q\quad\neg q}{p}{\sf DS}$$ This also does not apply here.

Answer (score 3):

From $Fa \lor Ga$ you cannot infer $Ga$, no matter what rule you try to use, since $Ga$ simply does not logically follow from $Fa \lor Ga$:  If $Fa$ is true but $Ga$ is false, then $Fa \lor Ga$ would be true, but $Ga$ false.

More importantly, however, the set-up of your proof is not correct in the first place. Given that you have $\exists x (Fx \lor Gx)$, you should start the subproof with $Fa \lor Ga$. Remember, to set up a $\exists$ Elim, drop the existential, and replace al instances of the quantified variable with a new constant.

Comment: Got it. Thank you! Should I start another sub-proof within it?

Comment: @notMW Yes, an inside subproof to do an $\lor$ Elim on $Fa \lor Ga$

Answer (score 1):

$\vee\mathsf E$, is the symbol for the "disjunction elimination" rule of inference, and this is the "Proof by Cases" rule.   Its inputs are (usually) a disjunction and two subproofs which assume each case in turn to derive the same conclusion.   Thus the disjunction is "eliminated" to derive the conclusion.

[A common variation is to accept a disjunction and two conditionals whose antecedents are the cases and share the same consequent.]

$$\dfrac{\lower{1ex}{p\vee q}~~\dfrac{\underset{\vdots}{[p]}^\bullet}{r}~\dfrac{\underset{\vdots}{[q]}^\bullet}{r}}{r}{\vee\mathsf E^\bullet}\qquad\dfrac{p\vee q\quad p\to r\quad q\to r}{r}{\vee\mathsf E}$$

---

So, **long story short** you have introduced a disjunction on line 3, but don't have the means to eliminate it: two subproofs, or two conditionals.

You are approaching it wrong.

---

What you need to do is assume a witness to the existential $\exists x~(Fx\vee Gx)$, that is $Fa\vee Ga$, and then eliminate this disjunction to derive the conclusion $\exists Fx\vee\exists Gx$.  Then use **existential elimination**.
$$\def\fitch#1#2{\quad\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline#2\end{array}}
\fitch{\exists x~(Fx\vee Gx)}{\fitch{\hspace{-4ex}[a]~Fa\vee Ga}{\fitch{Fa}{\vdots\\\exists x~Fx\vee\exists x~Gx}\\\fitch{Ga}{\vdots\\\exists x~Fx\vee\exists x~Gx}\\\exists x~Fx\vee\exists x~Gx\hspace{6ex}{\vee}\mathsf E}\\\exists x~Fx\vee \exists x~Gx\hspace{10ex}\exists\mathsf E}$$